# Improving Performance of a Procedure block with Huge volume of DML operations

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, transactions

Edit- Let me reconstruct the question.
In a recent interview for a position of PLSQL developer, I was asked a question like this:

There is a stored procedure which is getting executed simultaneously across multiple nodes, in short span of time. This is resulting in a lot of transactions(DML operations - INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE) happening on a table.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE high_vol_sp() AS

BEGIN

DML OPERATIONS
COMMIT;
END high_vol_sp;
```

I'm supposed to create a PLSQL stored procedure or modify the existing procedure such a way that it improves the performance of the high volume of DML operations.

How to improve the performance of the procedure block?
How will you approach this problem?
What type of SQL statements you would use to solve this problem?

Customer requirement is to write SQL queries to handle this situation.
No other documentation is supplied.

Its related to trading /core banking domain.
Can anyone give solution for this problem?

I thought of using collection array and FORALL to perform bulk insert.
But couldn't think of a solution for Update or delete.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make any sense. What problem is to be solved?

Comment: @AndrewSayer My bad. Apologies. I  have modified the question now. I beleive that should make some sense.

Comment: There could be any number of opportunities hidden in that 'dml operations' cloud.  And we don't know if the performance of a single execution, in isolation, is itself in need of improvement or if the problem is in collisions between multiple concurrent executions. 
"simultaneously across multiple nodes, in short span of time" could be contradictory.  "simultaneously" means exactly that.  "Across a short period of time" could be 10 executions in 3 seconds, but none of them actually simultaneously.

Comment: @EdStevens Consider this scenario. In stock markets, a trading application of a broker could place millions of orders for buying and selling of stocks. The bulk of the transactions happens within few seconds across systems, especially during the opening minute. Say, an update query is slowing down the process. What are all the steps that I could take to improve the performance of the query?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a stock market, a bank, or a local hardware store. If you have a need to reduce the time to completion of a transaction, the principles are the same.  Justin has outlined some good points.  But if your task is to re-write a specific procedure, you'd have to have the code to start with - and we don't have it. So it's really impossible to even make general comments directed at the code itself.  It could involve any number of bad practices that need to be corrected.

Comment: Thanks all of you guys for your valuable comments. It was immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably start with doing some sort of profiling of the code.  It doesn't make sense to try to improve performance unless you know what specifically is slow.  In an interview, that would give you the opportunity to talk about AWR, ADDR, and ASH reports, 10046 traces, etc.

Once you know what in the mass of DML is actually slow, you can start to tune.

- Start simple-- is some of the DML slow because of missing indexes?  If so, that's a quick and easy fix.
- Based on what you saw from profiling, is the problem with single-threaded performance?  Or is the problem that different threads are interfering with each other (i.e. you have some sort of lock contention)?  If you're trying to debug lock contention, you need to look at the order in which rows are locked and how the procedure is called to see if you can reorganize the callers to minimize contention-- if you have several calling threads, for example, you'd rather they be processing for different accounts rather than having all the calling threads processing different transactions for the same account.
- Is the code doing a lot of row-by-row processing?  If so, refactoring that into set-based processing can be a significant advantage.  This can include doing things like passing collections to procedures so that you don't have to call them in a loop.
- If you're doing a lot of row-by-row processing that can't be reasonably refactored, consider using collections with `bulk collect` and `forall`.
- Are there things that the procedure is doing that don't strictly need to be done synchronously?  If so, you can get significant improvements by factoring those out into separate jobs.  Something like sending emails is relatively easy to factor out but there are often other pieces of code that can be queued up and done by a different process asynchronously.

Any of these items would (potentially) impact all different types of DML-- none of them are specific to `select` statements vs. `insert`, `update`, and `delete` statements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Justin. Was helpful for me.